# configuring auto-generated buttons to display different values

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I have used a loop to turn a list of 4 values into a set of buttons. I need to overwrite the text of these buttons to contain the values of another list (in this case Ans2). any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def NextQuestion():
    print("this is where i need to configure the buttons to contain values from list - Ans2")

Ans1 = [6,5,32,7]
Ans2 = [4,9,3,75]

AnsNo = 0
r = 0
c = 0
for x in range(len(Ans1)):
    AnsBtn = tk.Button(root, text=(Ans1[AnsNo]), command = NextQuestion)
    AnsBtn.grid(row=r, column=c)
    AnsNo = AnsNo+1
    if r == 1:
        c = 1
        r = 0
    else:
        r = r+1
```

Comment: You mean you want to configure the clicked button to respectively change to whatever corresponds on the 2nd list? Like if I click the 2nd button, it must change from 5 to 9 and the remaining button must stay same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to store the buttons somewhere so they can be accessed to be changed. Then you just access their text variable and change it.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def NextQuestion():
    for i, button in enumerate(buttons):
        button["text"] = Ans2[i]

Ans1 = [6,5,32,7]
Ans2 = [4,9,3,75]

buttons = []

AnsNo = 0
r = 0
c = 0
for i,answer in enumerate(Ans1):
    AnsBtn = tk.Button(root, text=(answer), command = NextQuestion)
    AnsBtn.grid(row=r, column=c)
    buttons.append(AnsBtn)
    if r == 1:
        c = 1
        r = 0
    else:
        r = r+1

root.mainloop()
```